# Excel + how to extract string

Tags: excel

Excel 2013. 
I have got 1000 rows and I am trying to extract strings as follows :-

```
Column A:
Cell : A1  : ICC-->ICC - MRL&E-->TOP 100 industries             
Cell : A2  : APPS-->APPS - HCLS-->TOP 500 industries
```

I should write a formula so i get either the first 3 or 4 letters in column B.

```
Cell B1 : I should get ICC
Cell B2 : I should get APPS
```

I should write a formula so i get either the first 3 or 4 letters in column C.

```
Cell C1 : I should get MRL&E
Cell C2 : I should get HCLS
```

Formula used in `B1 = LEFT(A1,3)` /* Does not work when I need 4 char i.e., APPS

Formula used in `C1 = MID(A1,FIND("-->",A1)+9,4)` /* Does not work when I need 5 char i.e., MRL&E

Comment: You really should be using regular expressions for this problem.  But Excel does not have any built-in regex support, outside of VBA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what worked for me:

B1 `=LEFT(A1,FIND("-->",A1)-1)`

C1 `=MID(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("-->",A1)-2),FIND(" - ",RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("-->",A1)-2))+3,FIND("-->",RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("-->",A1)-2))-FIND(" - ",RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("-->",A1)-2))-3)`